# Is .NET framework needed for Classic ASP to run?

Tags: .net, asp-classic

I want to know whether .NET framework is needed for classic ASP to run or not.

I am also looking for tools (if any) which can help migrating a classic ASP page to .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic ASP was designed a long time ago before even .NET Framework was released, so unless your page needs to interoperate with .NET, there is no need to install or enable .NET Framework.

There is no way to migrate from classic ASP to ASP.NET. You have to start from scratch.